# New Repository unexpectedly adds other files

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I created a new repository for my first create-react-app and when I went to setup the remote connection to my github repository it failed. After going to my github repository I found files and even entire repositories had been added to both my local and Github repository, but they are not visible in my editor or desktop folder. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction as to what happened and how I can resolve this I would greatly appreciate it. Here is what I see when I run git status after attempting to push changes to my github repository:

```
 cam@Anduril  ~/Desktop/starting-react   Master ●  git status
On branch Master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   ../.DS_Store
    deleted:    ../Budget/css/all.css
    deleted:    ../Budget/css/bootstrap.min.css
    deleted:    ../Budget/css/main.css
    deleted:    ../Budget/index.html
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknell.css
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknell.html
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellabout.css
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellabout.html
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellcontact.css
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellcontact.html
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellmusic.css
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellmusic.html
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellshows.css
    deleted:    ../Death Knell/deathknellshows.html
    deleted:    ../READ.md
    modified:   ../color-game/index.html
    modified:   ../color-game/index.js
    modified:   ../color-game/styles.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell.htm
    deleted:    ../deathknell/.DS_Store
    deleted:    ../deathknell/amazonmusic.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/bandcamp.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknell.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknell.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellabout.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellabout.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellcontact.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellcontact.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellmusic.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellmusic.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellshows.css
    deleted:    ../deathknell/deathknellshows.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell/dkbackground.jpg
    deleted:    ../deathknell/dklanding.jpg
    deleted:    ../deathknell/facebook.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/insta.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/itunes.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/logo.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/spotify.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell/twitter.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/41uN8iSe7gL._SX301_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/Digital-Identity-Unpacked-1.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/api.js
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/app.html
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/cb=gapi(1).loaded_0
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/cb=gapi.loaded_0
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/death-of-liberty.jpg
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/email_grey600_24dp.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/fb_32x32.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(1)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(10)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(11)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(12)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(13)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(14)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(15)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(16)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(17)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(18)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(19)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(2)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(20)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(21)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(22)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(23)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(24)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(25)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(26)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(27)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(28)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(29)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(3)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(30)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(31)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(32)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(33)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(34)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(35)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(36)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(37)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(38)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(39)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(4)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(40)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(41)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(42)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(43)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(44)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(45)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(46)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(47)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(48)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(49)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(5)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(50)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(51)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(52)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(53)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(54)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(55)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(56)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(57)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(58)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(59)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(6)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(60)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(61)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(62)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(63)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(64)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(65)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(66)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(67)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(68)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(69)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(7)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(70)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(71)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(72)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(73)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(74)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(75)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(76)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(77)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(78)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(79)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(8)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(80)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(81)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(82)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(83)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(84)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(85)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(86)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(87)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(88)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(89)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(9)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(90)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/images(91)
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=BuhrE,GxIAgd,MkHyGd,NpD4ec,OG6ZHd,PygKfe,RI5Krb,RqxLvf,T6sTsf,T7XTS,URQPYc,Wq6lxf,XjCeUc,aa,aam1T,async,eN4qad,ebqyud,fEVMic,foot,lazG7b,m,mI3LFb,mUpTid,mu,o02Jie,pB6Zqd,qZ1Udb,qi,qik19b,rHjpXd,sb_wiz,sf,sonic,spch,str,uiNkee,ujFhWe,wft,wkrYee,xz7cCd,zb
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=FBWYne,mfkHA,ptS8Ie
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=GSWAyf,XeLme
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=Q7Rsec,d0xvhc
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=_b,_tp
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=qOaBwc
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/m=sYcebf
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/rs=AA2YrTs9lXdWY2A2Qw-5oWtGGTmrLlgIag
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/rs=AA2YrTsqFA6Alk0U0hqoEHSxPPrr1CyLow
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/rs=ACT90oGYE-hpqRt5BryEYHWoW-CQS2_X6A
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/spin-24.gif
    deleted:    ../deathknell_files/twitter_32x32.png
    deleted:    ../html:css/acme.css
    deleted:    ../html:css/acme.html
    deleted:    ../html:css/index.css
    deleted:    ../html:css/index.html
    deleted:    ../html:css/jsexercises.js
    deleted:    ../html:css/sample.jpg
    deleted:    ../html:css/survey.css
    deleted:    ../html:css/survey.html
    deleted:    ../html:css/tribute.css
    deleted:    ../html:css/tribute.html

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../.gitignore
    ../ArtsTaxReceipt.pdf
    ../Bootstrap 4/
    ../Bootstrap v3 practice/
    ../CS101.pdf
    ../CSS Grid Cardio/
    ../DeveloperResume.pdf
    ../FMG Suite Resume.pdf
    ../Frontend Mentor/
    ../Javascript Practice/
    ../Matt Garstka/
    ../MyShop/
    ../Patatap/
    ../Portfolio/
    ../TaxReturn.pdf
    ../Todo-list/
    ../acmeinner.html
    ../back/
    ../beginner-javascript-master/
    ../binarynotes.pdf
    ../color-game/README.md
    ../data_structures/
    ../deathknellv2/
    ../fontawesome-free-5.13.0-desktop/
    ../fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/
    ../html5up-read-only/
    ../html5up-solid-state/
    ../html:css/Bear.jpg
    ../html:css/IMG_4429.HEIC
    ../html:css/blog.css
    ../html:css/blog.html
    ../html:css/cssbasics.html
    ../html:css/debug.css
    ../html:css/html.png
    ../html:css/intro.html
    ../html:css/photoblog.html
    ../html:css/photos.css
    ../html:css/reset.css
    ../html:css/selectors.css
    ../html:css/technicaldoc.css
    ../html:css/technicaldoc.html
    ../mealpan ebook.pdf
    ../mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.0/
    ../photos.css
    ./

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 cam@Anduril  ~/Desktop/starting-react   Master ● 
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have created a git directory in your Desktop rather than in Desktop/starting-react

From the command line

`cd ~/Desktop` - change directory

`ls -a` - show files `-a` includes hidden files

If there is a `.git` directory

`rm -rf .git` - remove `.git` directory

`cd starting-directory`

`git init`